# On Excel VBA code, one macro works when ran by itself, but debugs when ran in a group

Tags: excel, vba

My program works by calling a number of macros as such:

```
Sub RunAll()
Call BenNaimGal
Call NunnariMaureen
Call FarberovDimitry

End Sub
```

My program breaks at the macro3 Call FarberovDimitry, which is essentially an exact replica of macro1 and macro2 which works fine. When macro3 is ran by itself it works perfectly, but when I attempt to run the entire program some rows are missing,

```
Rng4.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A5:AJ50")
```

A5:AJ50 is blank

Below are the code for those 3 macros

```
Sub BenNaimGal()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("A1:AJ14")
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet
Rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1:AJ20")
Rows(3).RowHeight = 36
Rows(4).RowHeight = 64.5
Rows("6:50").RowHeight = 15
Columns(11).ColumnWidth = 11.57
Columns(12).ColumnWidth = 30.43
Columns(14).ColumnWidth = 15.57
Columns(22).ColumnWidth = 14
Columns(24).ColumnWidth = 13.71
Columns(25).ColumnWidth = 13.71

Set column1 = Columns("A:J")
column1.Hidden = True
Set column2 = Columns("R:T")
column2.Hidden = True
Set column3 = Columns("M:M")
column3.Hidden = True
Set column4 = Columns("U:U")
column4.Hidden = True
Set column5 = Columns("W:W")
column5.Hidden = True
Set column6 = Columns("Z:AJ")
column6.Hidden = True
[N1].Value = "Gal"
[O1].Value = "Ben-Naim"
[N2].Value = "CA . PBI. 3410"

WS.SaveAs "L:\17_Year_End_KPIs\2018\Master KIP 2018 v1 - Distribution\Ben- 
Naim, Gal"

End Sub

Sub NunnariMaureen()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("A1:AJ4")
Set Rng2 = Range("A15:AJ25")
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet
Rng1.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1:AJ4")
Rng2.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A5:AJ50")
Rows(3).RowHeight = 36
Rows(4).RowHeight = 64.5
Rows("6:50").RowHeight = 15
Columns(11).ColumnWidth = 11.57
Columns(12).ColumnWidth = 30.43
Columns(14).ColumnWidth = 15.57
Columns(22).ColumnWidth = 14
Columns(24).ColumnWidth = 13.71
Columns(25).ColumnWidth = 13.71


Set column1 = Columns("A:J")
column1.Hidden = True
Set column2 = Columns("R:T")
column2.Hidden = True
Set column3 = Columns("M:M")
column3.Hidden = True
Set column4 = Columns("U:U")
column4.Hidden = True
Set column5 = Columns("W:W")
column5.Hidden = True
Set column6 = Columns("Z:AJ")
column6.Hidden = True
[N1].Value = "Nunnari"
[O1].Value = "Maureen"
[N2].Value = "CA . C&I. 3420"

WS.SaveAs "L:\17_Year_End_KPIs\2018\Master KIP 2018 v1 - 
Distribution\Nunnari, Maureen"

End Sub

Sub FarberovDimitry()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng3 = Range("A1:AJ4")
Set Rng4 = Range("A26:AJ33")
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet
Rng3.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1:AJ4")
Rng4.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A5:AJ50")
Rows(3).RowHeight = 36
Rows(4).RowHeight = 64.5
Rows("6:50").RowHeight = 15
Columns(11).ColumnWidth = 11.57
Columns(12).ColumnWidth = 30.43
Columns(14).ColumnWidth = 15.57
Columns(22).ColumnWidth = 14
Columns(24).ColumnWidth = 13.71
Columns(25).ColumnWidth = 13.71


Set column1 = Columns("A:J")
column1.Hidden = True
Set column2 = Columns("R:T")
column2.Hidden = True
Set column3 = Columns("M:M")
column3.Hidden = True
Set column4 = Columns("U:U")
column4.Hidden = True
Set column5 = Columns("W:W")
column5.Hidden = True
Set column6 = Columns("Z:AJ")
column6.Hidden = True
[N1].Value = "Dimitry"
[O1].Value = "Farberov"
[N2].Value = "CA . PBI. 3409"

WS.SaveAs "L:\17_Year_End_KPIs\2018\Master KIP 2018 v1 - 
Distribution\Farberov, Dimitry"

End Sub
```

Comment: you set the worksheet `Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet` but never use it to qualify any of the ranges.

Comment: how to change it? many thanks

Comment: append each range with `ws.` so `ws.Rows(3)` etc

Comment: appreciate your help, but it still doesn't work after I applied the ws.

Comment: What line errors? and please show the updated code.

Comment: You should declare your variables that are used in all 3 subs in your `RunAll` sub. You can then pass these along to each sub. That way, you only need to declare/initiate your `ws` and `Rng` variable once

Comment: Do you mean put Dim WS and rng in the RunAll sub and delete it in each macro? I tried but the problem still remains

Comment: Hi Scott, below are the change I made                                                              
    Sub FarberovDimitry()
    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:AJ4")
    Set Rng2 = Range("A26:AJ33")
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet
    Rng1.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1:AJ4")
    Rng2.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A5:AJ50")
    WS.Rows(3).RowHeight = 36
    WS.Rows(4).RowHeight = 64.5
    WS.Rows("6:50").RowHeight = 15
    WS.Columns(11).ColumnWidth = 11.57
    WS.Columns(12).ColumnWidth = 30.43
    WS.Columns(14).ColumnWidth = 15.57

Comment: You have a bunch of identical code repeated across those 3 subs which could be moved to a separate "FormatSheet" Sub which takes a worksheet as a argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to specify a sheet of rng.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim myWs As Worksheet

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set Rng = myWs.Range("A1:AJ14")
```

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate it!!